# how to add map values in to a list in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dictionary

I want to create a `List` and add values like this, but im new with flutter so i don't know

```
     {
        'studAttId': 'null',
        'divisionId': '4365eb0b-fb48-42f9-be4e-e9c1c695aeab',
        'id': 'e49d6d0d-0036-417c-a0ff-330e51cb947d',
        'forenoon': 'P',
        'afternoon': 'P',
        'admNo': '496',
        'rollNo': 'null',
        'name': 'A M MUHAMMED AFSAL',
        'terminatedStatus': 'null'
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
yourList.add({
        'studAttId': 'null',
        'divisionId': '4365eb0b-fb48-42f9-be4e-e9c1c695aeab',
        'id': 'e49d6d0d-0036-417c-a0ff-330e51cb947d',
        'forenoon': 'P',
        'afternoon': 'P',
        'admNo': '496',
        'rollNo': 'null',
        'name': 'A M MUHAMMED AFSAL',
        'terminatedStatus': 'null'
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, preferably you can reformat the type of your map like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> yourMap = { 
    'studAttId': 'null',
    'divisionId': '4365eb0b-fb48-42f9-be4e-e9c1c695aeab',
    'id': 'e49d6d0d-0036-417c-a0ff-330e51cb947d',
    }



 List<dynamic> yourList = []
 yourList.addAll(yourMap.values)
```